# Visualising Multiple Routes from pgrouting in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pgrouting

I am able to Visualise the Single Route from Source A to Target B by the following code

in QGIS SQL

```
"id" in (
SELECT id2 as id
 FROM pgr_dijkstra(
   'SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM ways',
   12746, 12714, false, false
 ) as a left join ways b on a.id2=b.id)
```

But when I try to load multiple paths (4 in this case)  using K-shortest path, Results are segments are scattered all over in different places and I do not see single proper route.

```
"id" in (
SELECT id2 as id
 FROM pgr_ksp(
   'SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM ways',
   12746, 12714, 4, false
 ) a LEFT JOIN ways b ON (a.id2 = b.id)
```

I am very beginner to pgrouting, so help me if i am doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution to it,

By using the following code, it is possible to visualise all the routes properly

```
"id" in (
SELECT id3 as id
 FROM pgr_ksp(
   'SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM ways',
   12746, 12714, 4, false
 ) a LEFT JOIN ways b ON (a.id3 = b.id))
```